# Send HTTP PUT request to Cloudant

Tags: java, httpurlconnection, put, cloudant

I am trying to send HTTP PUT request to Cloudant database to update a key "BPInc" to "N". Its current value is "Y". I am using HTTPURLConnection to make the connection and send request. I am able to send GET request successfully and retrieve the BPInc value. But when I am sending the PUT request, I am getting error code - 400.

I have also looked into cloudant-client library, but not able to get how to send PUT request and I want to stick to HTTPURLConnection method only.

Here's the code ,

```
// After retrieving _rev and _id using GET request......
String revID = "_rev of the document";
String docID = "_id of the document";
 URL postUrl = new URL("<Cloudant URL>/<DB NAME>/" + docID);
 String usernameColonPassword = "<API KEY>:<PASSWORD>";
          String basicAuthPayload = "Basic " + Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(usernameColonPassword.getBytes());
          HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection)postUrl.openConnection();
          conn.setRequestMethod("PUT");
          conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json; utf-8");
          conn.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
          conn.setRequestProperty("Authorization", basicAuthPayload);
          conn.setDoOutput(true);
          OutputStreamWriter json = new OutputStreamWriter(conn.getOutputStream());
          json.write(String.format("{\"_rev\":revID, \"BPInc\":\"Y\"}"));
          json.flush();
          json.close();

          int putResponseCode = conn.getResponseCode();
```

I am very new to this so I suppose I might be doing wrong something. Please suggest.

Comment: Sorry for type error. Current value of "BPInc" is "N" and I want to update it to "Y".

Comment: At `json.write`. 1) your json is wrong. You need to put `revID` between `\"`, because it's a string. 2) you use wrong `String.format`. It should be `String.format("{\"_rev\":\"%s\", \"BPInc\":\"Y\"}", revID)`. I also recommend to read this https://dzone.com/articles/java-string-format-examples , it's about `String.format`